# How can I use Light SearchView on Dark App Bar on android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, searchview, android-appbarlayout

This is my main activity xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />
```

This is my styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

The problem is that I want to use white text on the AppBar, but at the same time I want the search suggestions to have dark text on white background (like holo). Currently the suggestions are shown in dark theme. If I use ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar, then the suggestions turn white but the text on appbar is turned Black, and I want it to remain white.

Please help me! I am also attaching screenshots for demonstration purposes:

1. This has white title text.
2. see the dropdown suggestions? they should be white-themed.
   [image: This has white title text]
   [image: see the dropdown suggestions? they should be white-themed.]

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I succeeded to achieve that:

You need to override the styles `autoCompleteTextViewStyle` and `textAppearanceSearchResultTitle` in your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/myAutoCompleteTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSearchResultTitle">@style/mySearchResult</item>

    ...
</style>

<style name="myAutoCompleteTextViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/White</item>
</style>

<style name="mySearchResult" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
</style>
```